# PC Keyboard on Macbook Pro on Windows via Bootcamp

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-10, keyboard, macbook, boot-camp

I am thinking of getting a PC Keyboard for my Macbook Pro, but specifically for use when I'm running bootcamp for Windows. I'm assuming it would work just fine, so long as I get the appropriate drivers. Anyone have any previous experience doing something like this? If it matters, I'm specifically doing it for Excel for a business class I'll be in. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Windows support software](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204923) from Apple has the drivers you need to support a regular keyboard (non-apple). For keyboard mapping, this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/970299) gives you a list of equivalencies.